# How to add trusted ca in manjaro?

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, manjaro

It should be a pretty simple but i cant do it. What i tried:

```
cp pets.crt /etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors/
sudo trust extract-compat
sudo update-ca-trust extract
openssl verify pets.crt
```

I on the last point i am getting error:

```
sudo openssl verify pets.crt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
CN = api.pets.kruts.net
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self-signed certificate
error pets.crt: verification failed
```

And whatever i do it is the same. My company gave me this cert//

Answer (score 1):

In Manjaro to import a local crt you must first store the cert with the **trust** command that allow manage the policy store items.

```
sudo trust anchor /path/to/the/root.crt
sudo update-ca-trust
```

now in the store you run the **update-ca-trust** to finish. You don't need to do anything else.

the **trust anchor** command by default --store the crt if no flag is passed.